# Not all Cookies showing in Temporary Internet Files?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9, cookies

I'm running Internet Explorer 9, and had a question. Say I set up a site in PHP. In the PHP code I set a cookie with the name 'user' and value "test". When I go into my temporary internet files folder (C:\Users(user name)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files, I see cookies for YouTube, Bing, Twitter, and some other things, but none for my 'user' cookie. when I F12 the page and select Cache -> View Cookie Information, I see the cookie name ('user'), value ('test'), domain ('zzl.org'), path ('/'), and when it expires (at the end of the session).

Any ideas where I might be able to find (and edit) the cookie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cookies in Windows 7 are stored in these 2 other locations

Depending on your UAC configuration, Windows may use the first folder or the second one.

> C:\Users\Your User Name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies
>
> C:\Users\Your User Name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies\Low

Answer (score 4):

As I understand it, session cookies are only stored in memory since they are no longer valid after the session ends.